# Can I get "cons list" behaviour from a std::tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

I want to recursively define a function that sets all the elements of a std::tuple.  If it were a boost::tuple, I would simply look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_advanced_interface.html) and copy this example:

```
inline void set_to_zero(const null_type&) {};

template <class H, class T>
inline void set_to_zero(cons<H, T>& x) { x.get_head() = 0; set_to_zero(x.get_tail()); }
```

So far I can't find anything nearly that straightforward for std::tuple.  Is there anything close?

UPDATE: Okay, I need to flesh out the problem a bit more.

```
template<typename T>
struct simple_setter
{
    void set(T &target);  // somebody else's stuff, defined elsewhere
};


template<typename Tuple> class foo;

template<>
struct foo<boost::tuple<>>
{
    foo()  {}
    void set(boost::tuple<> &target)  {}
};

template<typename E, typename... Es>
struct foo<boost::tuple<E, Es...>>
{
    explicit foo(const simple_setter<E> &head_setter, const simple_setter<Es> & ... other_setters) :
         _head(head_setter),
         _tail(other_setters)
    {}

    void set(boost::tuple<E, Es...> &target) {
        _head.set(target.get_head()),
        _tail.set(target.get_tail())
    }

    // more methods to do other things

    const simple_setter<E> &_head;
    const foo<boost::tuple<Es ...>> _tail;
};
```

I'm writing the class foo that wraps a tuple, in order to do a bunch of things, just one of which is setting all the elements.  I was hoping to keep this sort of recursive definition of foo, but to make the switch from boost::tuples to std::tuples.

Comment: Why recursive? Why not set all elements to zero at once?

Comment: I was looking for the simplest form of my problem, but I see I simplified too far.  I'll work on a less drastic simplification for presentation here, but meanwhile what did you have in mind for setting all the elements at once?

Comment: `template <typename...T> void set_to_zero(std::tuple<T...>& t) { t = std::tuple<T...>{}; }` comes to mind as a simple way to set an entire tuple to a value-initialized state. I suppose you could make it more generic: `template <typename T> void set_to_zero(T& t) { t = T{}; }` and it will zero anything. Probably of little help to your more general problem, though.

Comment: `boost::tuple` actually is implemented recursively. I actually think the `std::tuple` still has to be implemented recursively, but the specification does not define access to `.tail()`.

Comment: @JanHudec: Nope, and the recursive implementation is actually both more complicated and less efficient.

Comment: @Xeo: Hm, I've looked and it's kind of recursive, but it does not look like cons pairs, but as chain of templates that each know it's own index. Which means the tuple can't be easily split to head and tail, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion can be implemented that way

```
template < typename _Tuple >
inline void set_to_zero(_Tuple& tuple, std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>)
{ 
}

template < typename _Tuple, size_t N >
inline void set_to_zero(_Tuple& tuple, std::integral_constant<size_t, N>)
{
    set_to_zero(tuple, std::integral_constant<size_t, N - 1>());
//  action(std::get<N - 1>(tuple));
}

template < typename _Tuple >
inline void set_to_zero(_Tuple& tuple)
{ 
    set_to_zero(tuple, std::integral_constant<size_t, std::tuple_size<_Tuple>::value>());
}
```

or more general form

```
template < typename _Tuple, typename _Func >
inline void for_each(_Tuple& tuple, _Func func_, std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>)
{
}

template < typename _Tuple, typename _Func, size_t N >
inline void for_each(_Tuple& tuple, _Func func_, std::integral_constant<size_t, N>)
{
    for_each(tuple, func_, std::integral_constant<size_t, N - 1>());
    func_(std::get<N - 1>(tuple));
}

template < typename _Tuple, typename _Functor >
inline void for_each(_Tuple& tuple, _Functor func_)
{
    for_each(tuple, func_, std::integral_constant<size_t, std::tuple_size<_Tuple>::value>()); 
}
```

usage sample of generalized form

```
    struct DoSomething
    {
        void operator()(int a)  {} // overload for int
        void operator()(double a) {} // overload for double
    };

    std::tuple<int, double> tuple_;

    for_each(tuple_, DoSomething());
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm thinking your "more general form" is in one respect less general.  In the first form you called "action", which might choose different overloads for elements of different types; whereas in your second form the same "func_" is called everywhere.  So you might choose the first form, for the sake of picking up the overloads of "action".  But then if you wanted the same pattern for overloaded function another_action and yet_another_action, you'd have to write the recursion out again and again ... or is there some way to have your cake and eat it here?

Comment: A functor is not necessary a function. It also could be a class which defines the operator().

Comment: See usage sample at the end of the answer